# Blas GEMM launch failed in tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

Hi I am trying to run the code of Machine learning algorithm

However, when I run the code I always get the below error Blas GEMM launch failed

I use the Geforce RTX 3070, CUDA 11.4 cuDNN 8.2. and Tensorflow 1.15.0 and python 3.7 version IDE is VSC

I thought this was from the memory problem of the GPU and I wrote a code to solve it but it didn't work. Also, I erase the cache file in the Nvidia to save more space but it also didn't work

are there any solutions to overcome this issue? or is this problem related to compatibility????

Please help me genius stack overflow users !!!

```
**Exception has occurred: InternalError
Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(5000, 3), b.shape=(3, 20), m=5000, n=20, k=3
     [[node MatMul (defined at C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1748) ]]
Original stack trace for 'MatMul':
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.11.1422169775\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.11.1422169775\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.11.1422169775\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)**
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There is problem with `TensorFlow-GPU` version `build configurations` compatibility in your system.

You need to install `CUDA 10` and `cudnn 7.4` specifically to be compatible to run your code with `tensorflow_gpu-1.15.0` and `Python 3.7` environment.

You can find the [build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) details in this link and can install [GPU support](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup) requirements as per your `system OS`.